# How to dispatch without connect

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I want to dispatch without a component. I made this code:

```
const handleClient = () => (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: "SET_CLIENT",
      user: {
        id: 1,
        name: "client",
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
export default handleLogin;
```

But this code doesn't work. I import this file and use that in onSubmit event. I use Redux-Thunk.
@Edit
Look at this code from tutorial

```
export const fetchContacts = () => (dispatch) => {
  fetch("https://myapi.local/contacts)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => dispatch(contactsFetched(json.results)));
};
```

I done something similar and it works so I don't understand that in this example it doesn't work. I tryed other method

```
import actions from "./actions";
import store from "../store";
const handleClient = () =>  {
    try{
        
        store.dispatch(actions.setClient({id: 1, name: 'Hello'}));
    } catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
}
export default handleClient;
```

but it doesn't work too.

Comment: You should give us more details about your reducers and actions and where you want to use it and what it should do. Based on your code, we can just suppose some things, but can't answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

https://redux.js.org/api/store#dispatchaction

You need to have access to your instance of the redux store, which you created somewhere in your codebase via `createStore()`. Then it's just `store.dispatch(handleclient())`.

Please keep in mind that this is usually a rare requirement and potentially a code smell. Why is your thunk not triggered from within a React component?

Comment: No, access to an instance of the store is not needed when using Redux-Thunk (unless I misunderstood what you mean).

Comment: @Guillaume The question is about using `dispatch` outside of react. The only way to dispatch actions without using `connect()` or `useDispatch()` I'm aware of is with the store instance directly. When you're using redux-thunk you still need to dispatch the thunk action itself somehow (regardless of the dispatch *inside* the thunk).

Comment: I Updated my post. Look at this.

Answer (score -1):

You should never use `store.dispatch`, so your first example is incorrect. Your second example is better, but the only place where you can use `useDispatch` is inside a function component or a custom hook, you cannot use it inside a callback like `handleLogin`.
Try to use `useDispatch` at the beginning of your React component and then pass the dispatch function as an argument to `handleLogin`.

Comment: Could you tell my why second code (with fetch) works but my code not? I use something similar in other file and it works. Using a few method to this same action is incorrect in my opinion.

Comment: Using `store.dispatch` is incorrect.

Comment: And the code with fetch is a thunk while your function appears to be a callback. Those are two very different kinds of functions which deal with dispatching very differently.

Comment: So, could I usa dispatch like in function with fetch?

Comment: @Guillaume Why do you say that you should never use store.dispatch when it exists as an api? https://redux.js.org/api/store#dispatchaction This is just an incorrect blanket statement. Also you keep mentioning useDispatch which is a react-redux hook, while OP clearly states that they are working outside of a react context.

Comment: @timotgl The question has the `react-redux` tag and the OP was using `useDispatch` in the question when I answered it (but for some reason it was removed since then). Where did you see that it is outside of a React context?

Comment: @Kapibara231 I’m not sure what you mean by "like in function with fetch". The example with fetch is a thunk, which is a special type of action (only available when using Redux Thunk) that gives you access to dispatch. Otherwise, the only other places where you have access to dispatch is in a component or in a custom hook (using `useDispatch`)

Comment: @Kapibara231 It would help a lot if you showed how `fetchContacts` and `handleClient` are used in your app.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie The first line of the question says "I want to dispatch without a component." and the title of the question is "How to dispatch without connect". This to me is a strong indication that someone is trying to dispatch a redux action without being in the context of react all. And in such a scenario, store.dispatch is the only way (that I know of) to accomplish this. I do agree that the question is clearly mislabeled with "react-redux". OP didn't really provide enough info to clear up this confusion. I think OP tried useDispatch because they thought it would work outside react.